# Converting Client-Side Firebase Google Authentication and Redirection to Server-Side Node.js Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm having trouble transitioning my authentication and redirection process from client-side Firebase using Google authentication to server-side code in Node.js. I'm seeking guidance on how to convert this functionality to be handled on the server, as I'm unfamiliar with the process. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

```
// firebase.js

import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app.js';
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithRedirect,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signOut,
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-auth.js';

import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  getDocs,
  serverTimestamp,
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-firestore.js';



export const firebaseConfig = {
    
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
  // Your Firebase configuration
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const db = getFirestore(app); // Use getFirestore to get the Firestore instance

export { db, collection, getDocs };
const cardLogin = document.getElementById('card-login');
const userImage = document.getElementById('user-image'); // assuming you have an element for the user image
const userApp = document.getElementById('user-app');
const userName = document.getElementById('user-name');
const btnLogout = document.getElementById('logout');

// Function to update the UI based on the user's authentication state
// Function to update the UI based on the user's authentication state
export const updateUI = (user) => {
  const userNameElement = document.getElementById('userName'); // Replace 'userName' with the actual ID of your element
  const userImageElement = document.getElementById('user-image'); // Replace 'user-image' with the actual ID of your image element
  const userEmailElement = document.getElementById('user-email'); // Replace 'user-email' with the actual ID of your element
  
  if (userNameElement && userImageElement && userEmailElement) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in
      const userName = user.displayName || 'N/A';
      const userPhotoURL = user.photoURL || '';
      const userEmail = user.email || 'N/A';
      // Update the UI with the retrieved data
      userNameElement.innerHTML = userName;
      userImageElement.src = userPhotoURL;
      userEmailElement.innerHTML = userEmail;
      // You can also store this information globally, e.g., in the window object
      window.userProfile = {
        userName,
        userEmail,
        userPhotoURL,
      };
    } else {
      // User is signed out
       // window.location.href = '/signin';
      // Handle the logic for a signed-out user, for example:
      console.log('User is signed out');
    }
  } else {
    console.error('Could not find elements with provided IDs.');
  }
};

// Listen for changes in the authentication state
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  updateUI(user);
     if (user) {
    // User is signed in
    // Check if the current URL is not already '/profile'
    if (window.location.pathname == '/signin') {
      // Redirect to the profile page after successful authentication
      window.location.href = '/profile';
    }
  } else if (window.location.pathname == '/profile'){ window.location.href = '/signin';}
});

// Function to handle Google sign-in
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  
  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      const user = result.user;
    
      userName.innerHTML = user.displayName;
     // Display the "redirect" message before redirecting to profile page
  
      // Display the "redirect" message before redirecting to profile page
      const redirectMessage = document.getElementById('redirectMessage');
      redirectMessage.style.display = 'block';

      // Wait for a short time to ensure the message is displayed
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Redirect to the profile page
        window.location.href = '/profile';
      }, 100); // Adjust or remove the delay if necessary
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      const email = error.email;
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      console.log(errorCode);
    });
};

// Function to handle user logout
export const signOutUser = () => {
  // Remove authorization-related data here if needed

  signOut(auth)
    .then(() => {
      // Sign-out successful.
      // Optionally, you can redirect the user to another page after logout
      window.location.href = '/signin';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // An error happened.
      console.log('Error logout', error);
    });
};
```

Server.js Example only ([Github Repository](https://github.com/satansdeer/firebase-server-auth/blob/master/step-2/server.js))

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const csrf = require("csurf");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://server-auth-41acc.firebaseio.com",
});

const csrfMiddleware = csrf({ cookie: true });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);
app.use(express.static("static"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrfMiddleware);

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", req.csrfToken());
  next();
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  res.render("login.html");
});

app.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
  res.render("signup.html");
});

app.get("/profile", function (req, res) {
  const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || "";

  admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((userData) => {
      console.log("Logged in:", userData.email)
      res.render("profile.html");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.redirect("/login");
    });
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index.html");
});

app.post("/sessionLogin", (req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();

  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;

  admin
    .auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
      (sessionCookie) => {
        const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true };
        res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
      },
      (error) => {
        res.status(401).send("UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!");
      }
    );
});

app.get("/sessionLogout", (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("session");
  res.redirect("/login");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```